# Update Metro App UI ObservableCollection from Background Task

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, background-process

Is two-way communication possible between a `BackgroundTask` and a Metro App UI?

The desired functionality is as follows:

- If Metro App is closed/suspended, `BackgroundTask` continues to do what
  is required.
- If Metro App is open/resumed, `BackgroundTask` continues to do what
  is required, but also notifies the Metro App, that new data is
  available.
- Metro App then updates its UI with the new data.    Metro    App UI
  allows user to take certain actions.
- These actions are `Queued` in memory. `BackgroundTask` monitors
  this memory `Queue` and processes these actions.

Please advise if this is possible, or suggest a design to meet these requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good detailed understanding of BackgroundTasks here:

[Introduction to BackgroundTasks](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411)

Which implicitly answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a background `thread` or a `Task`

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
   // Download data 
}).ContinueWith(t => 
{
   // Update UI
}, Scheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

The `ContinueWith` in the synchronization context is important because you will get an exception for updating an `ObservableCollection` from a different thread, you can also use the `Dispatcher` to execute a code block on the UI thread.

---

Above text remain to show original answer:

The MSDN guidelines for background tasks as linked [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977051.aspx) clearly state:

1. Background tasks shouldn't update the UI at all except for system UI like notifications etc
2. Background tasks should communicate with the application via persistent storage

Your problem needs to be addressed by maintaining a "new data" storage for your application, the background worker will download data and write it here, your application when resumed / opened will check and remove that data allowing you update your UI - the storage acts as your in-the-middle queue.

Comment: Well then, you don't need to update the UI do you? In fact, the MSDN guidelines tell you explicitly not to so your question is moot. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977051.aspx If instead you're asking for a way to queue tasks and then have them picked up by a background task then you should have asked that question instead.

Comment: @c0D3l0g1c the guidelines I linked state that you should use persistent storage to communicate between your application and background-task, if your app is closed / suspended then you'd have a problem. You'll need to push any data downloaded by the task into storage which your app will then pick up when it's resumed / started again.

Comment: @c0D3l0g1c essentially yes, background task won't do it itself, you'll have to do it, the MSDN pages are always a good place to start for the Microsoft technologies, especially if you're not familiar with them.